# Sending custom response from RequestBodyAdviceAdapter

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

How can I send a custom response from the afterBodyRead method in RequestBodyAdviceAdapter?

I am using afterBodyRead to validate a json object with jsonschema. If the validation is incorrect I want to send a response to the client with the information about the error.

```
@Override
    public Object afterBodyRead(Object body, HttpInputMessage inputMessage, MethodParameter parameter,
                                Type targetType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
        String json = (new Gson()).toJson(body);
        try {
            validator.checkSchema(schema, new JSONObject(json));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            //redirect or return customized error
        }
        return body;
    }
```

I don't have a HttpResponse in the afterBodyRead, so I cannot return the message. Is there any way to return an error message to the client?

Comment: Have you tried throwing an exception and using `@ExceptionHandler`?

Comment: Yes, I tried, but the correct way is throwing a RuntimeException.

Answer (score 0):

Just I needed to throw a RuntimeException.